# How does sympy handle exponents to the 0.5 power?

Tags: python, floating-point, sympy

```
((gamma-(gamma**2-omega**2)**0.5)*(gamma+(gamma**2-omega**2)**0.5)).simplify()
```

The output is:
gamma^2 - (gamma^2 -omega^2)^{1.0} $

However, I expected the result to be omega^2. I know in the sympy docs, it warns about being careful with floating point numbers, but I was under the impression that integers and also fractional powers of 2 (which can be represented exactly) were fine.

The following code correctly reproduces omega^2:

```
((gamma-(gamma**2-omega**2)**sym.Rational(1,2))*(gamma+(gamma**2-omega**2)**sym.Rational(1,2))).simplify()
```

Why does the first code not produce the expected result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SymPy considers that there is a distinction between *exact* and *inexact* numbers. In this context floats like `0.5` and `1.0` are considered to be inexact and therefore it is not clear that `x**1.0` is really equal to `x` or equal to something slightly different like say `x**1.00000000000000000000001`. That is because floats usually arise from floating point calculations which can have rounding errors. In your example the result is:

```
In [5]: from sympy import *

In [6]: gamma, omega = symbols('gamma, omega')

In [7]: e = ((gamma-(gamma**2-omega**2)**0.5)*(gamma+(gamma**2-omega**2)**0.5)).simplify()

In [8]: e
Out[8]: 
              1.0
 2   ⎛ 2    2⎞   
γ  - ⎝γ  - ω ⎠
```

If you want to tell SymPy that the `1.0` should be treated as an exact `1` then you can use SymPy's `nsimplify` function:

```
In [9]: nsimplify(e)
Out[9]: 
 2
ω
```

Comment: Very informative answer; thank you also for the nsimplify function. If I understand you correctly, python can represent 0.5 exactly,  but the "incorrect answer" is a result of SymPy's expected behavior with floats.

Comment: The point is that SymPy will usually refuse to simplify a *possibly* inexact result into something that *looks* like an exact result. Once you have used floats the expression is tainted with inexactness and should remain so, regardless of whether particular numbers like `0.5` or `1.0` can be represented exactly as floats. Every floating point number can be represented exactly as a float but if it arises from floating point operations its value might not be the true exact result of those operations.